# Filtrar Datos a un solo excel - PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, jupyter

Hola gente tengo una consulta, tengo dos excel de una empresa de los cuales filtre a uno le obtuve el OP Y EL CUSTOMER CLI y del otro excel saque el OP y el DEPOSITO pero al concatenarlo me pone dos mini tablas en un excel, el problema es que los OP pueden ser iguales algunos entonces necesito de los dos excel hacer una misma tabla que tenga OP CUSTOMER CLI Y DEPOSITO sin que se transcriban si el OP es igual que me ponga customer cli y deposito se entiende ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import glob
import xlwt

Exc_operaciones = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Masi/Desktop/Logistica/OPERACIONES 0101 al 1806 PM.xlsx')
Exc_fw = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Masi/Desktop/Logistica/FW 0101_2019 al 1806_2020.xlsx')
Exc_impo = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Masi/Desktop/Logistica/CNTRs IMPO.xlsx')
Exc_PM = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Masi/Desktop/Logistica/CNTR 0101 al 1806 20PM.xlsx')

data_Frame1 = pd.read_excel(Exc_operaciones)
data_Frame2 = pd.read_excel(Exc_PM)

value1= data_Frame1[["OP","CUSTOMER CLI"]]
value2= data_Frame2[["OP","DEPOSITO"]]

data1=[value1,value2]

join  = pd.concat(data1)

join.to_excel('C:/Users/Masi/Desktop/sales1.xls')

data1
```

[image: me crea dos mini tablas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo que muestras, se puede resolver indicando `axis=1`.

O sea:

```
join  = pd.concat(data1,axis=1)
```

Pero el problema es que necesitas tener el campo `OP` ordenado, eso significa..

```
value1 --> index 0 op=1, index 1 op=2 .... index n op= n
value2 --> index 0 op=1, index 1 op=2 .... index n op= n
```

Si ese orden no se cumple, necesitaríamos cambiar de estrategia.

**Edición (Verificar filas duplicadas)**:

Para comparar que no hayan filas duplicadas en cada `DataFrame`, podemos usar un condicional que nos informe que se han encontrado registros duplicados de la siguiente manera:

Guardar el mini dataframe con registros duplicados y mostrarlos si la cantidad de registros es mayor a 0.

```
duplicados_value1 = value1[value1.duplicate()]
if len(duplicados_value1) > 0:
    print(f"Se encontraron {len(duplicados_value1)} registros duplicados en value1")
    display(duplicados_value1)
```

Para `value2` seguiría la misma lógica. Ahora bien, dentro del `True`, podemos agregar "quitar duplicados" eso se hace utilizando `.drop_duplicates()` (retorna un `DataFrame` con los registros *únicos*), y acá tenemos una función que recibe parámetros y de ellos depende su comportamiento, lo normal (por asi llamarlo) sería usar `value1 = value1.drop_duplicates()`, ya que en la imagen se ve que estas usando `jupyter notebook`, puedes colocar el puntero dentro del paréntesis y *tipear* `SHIFT+TAB`. Se abrirá un cuadro con información de los parámetros que recibe y su respectivo *Docstring*.

Para este caso sugiero utilizar [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) .

Una solución podría ser:

```
result = pd.merge(value1,value2,on='OP',how='outer')
```

El resultado obtenido es similar al de un `join` en `sql`, donde el parametro `how` va a recibir el tipo de `join` a realizar (`left,right,outer,inner`).

En tu caso se puede apreciar que `value2` tiene 1815 filas, y `value1` 1105. Entonces deberás definir el tipo de `join` deseado.

Comment: entiendo , lo hice y se agregan  peeero se me duplican muchas , puede ser que originalmente tenga duplicados alguno de los dos excel ?

Comment: primero verifica que value1 y value2 no poseen valores duplicados

Comment: soy nuevo en pandas perdon , como puedo hacer para corroborar que no tengas duplicados ? y si hay duplicados que los elimine

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109665/room-for-lucas-damian-and-maxi-pintos